# Amazon Elastic Load Balancer throwing connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have added a route 53 entry A.B.com and it points to my ELB.

I set up a script that makes http calls to this end point - http://A.B.com/xxx

However, I see that every 70th or 80th request is throwing a "connection timeout" [not a read timeout]

Can anyone help me how to debug this issue?

Here is my script -

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
while [ $n -le 5 ]
do
        curl -s -D - "http://A.B.com/xxx"
done
```

**Note**
I do not use VPC

**CloudWatch**

1. **HTTPCode_Backend_5XX** ~ 200 (mean)
2. **SurgeQueueLength** ~ 1000 (mean)

Do these parameters in CloudWatch mean my backend is unhealthy..?

I changed the ELB for the time being.. things are ok as of now.. but I am not sure I found the root cause..